# Iterate through big list or get result from the server in android - compare battery usage

Tags: android

I have big list with branches from the server. Every of this branches has location and I need to find the nearest branch for exact location. I can:
 1. get the result from the server that would contain one branch
 2. or to Iterate over all branches and test them for this case.
What would be the impact on the battery in both cases?
Which is better?

I always have all branches on the mobile side at the very begging, because I list them in the app. So there is no question what I would do first , before 1 or 2. First stage is always having all branches. After that I have the two options and I need to know **how to compare battery usage** for case of:
1. making internet request 
2. iterating through the big list

I don't care which Java programming pattern is better. I just need low battery usage.

Answer (score 1):

**Normal scenario:**

Make a request => get all the branches in response => Perform selection query => Get the desired branch => display it

**Optimized scenario:**

Make a request => Get the selected branch in response => display it

**Description:**

Considering mobile battery and resources, complex logic should be written on the server side, so it would be easier for application to make a request, get the data and display the same into the application. Plus it would be faster too!

Faster in the sense, you have to make a web request in any case, considering server capabilities you should perform complex logic and operations on server side because it would be faster as compared to mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On mobile side I already have all the branches. I'm sure that would be easier to get the nearest branches from the server, but why would be faster? The server response time is not constant value.   Also I don't get the example for the login screen. Usually I don't need data for login screen. I sent what is already entered (credentials) to the server to get the whole user object and always would get the whole object. What is the point to get just part of the object and then to make one more request to get the whole user object , although is for other activity.

Comment: Login example was just for the reference, for which you would just need to verify the username and password and so would not require any other details!